# User is not associated with a trusted sql server connection - non-domain computer

Tags: sql-server-2005, windows-authentication

I'm trying to connect using several different clients to SQL Server 2005 standard, which has been configured to use Windows Authentication.  Although the user account exists on the domain, the computer is not joined to the domain.  I get the message, "user is not associated with a trusted sql server connection".  The question [The user is not associated with a trusted SQL Server connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/851549/the-user-is-not-associated-with-a-trusted-sql-server-connection) helpfully suggests that I set the SQL server to allow both Windows Authentication and SQL Authentication.  I'd rather just stick to Windows Authentication.  Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. To use Windows Authentication, the machines must be on the same domain. If the machines are not on the same domain (or there is no trust relationship between the domain the server is on and the machine is on), neither will know which domain to use to authenticate the user against (even if the account exists).

Comment: Thank you for responding.  I'm willing to accept that and move on, but it seems weird that windows servers will accept a non-domain computer for file sharing but not database sharing. Also, this page http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/31792004/windows-authentication-from-outside-the-domain.aspx hints that it might be possible.

Comment: Perhaps it would make a difference that the client machine doesn't belong to any domain.

Answer (score 1):

If the user exists on both domains/computers with the same username/password, it will work.  So in your example you would create a new account on the computer running SQL Server with the same username and password as the domain account you are connecting from.

Not ideal if you have a password policy and need to change the password every so often because you always need to keep them in sync, but it works for a temporary fix or non-production usage.