# this user is not associated

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2005, connection

Machine X (hoster pc with SQL Server 2005 Express edition installed and also known as development PC)

Machine Y (unknown user or guest)

I can both set and get data from machine X but when friends try to do that they get the following error

> the user is not associated with a
>   trusted sql server connection

I use windows auth.. my connection string is the following:

`string ConnectionString="Data Source=IP.IP.IP.IP,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=SSPI;";`

I checked everything but it seems like a permission problem in SQL or my computer.
the firewall is turned off and so is AVG antivirus

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you allow remote connections?  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/914277

Comment: Yes, i did all the steps for a remote connection, but the problem seems like the other pc is taking the connection in action BUT fails in authentication.

Iam also trying to log in my SSMS2005 by using SQL user:sa and password but getting the error 18456: user log in failed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [The user is not associated with a trusted SQL Server connection.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/851549/the-user-is-not-associated-with-a-trusted-sql-server-connection)

Answer (score 2):

The error means pretty much what it says - the SQL Server can't authenticate the user.

This typically happens when the user is not logged in as a member of the domain, for instance, if they're logging in to their machines under an account that is specific to that machine instead of using their domain account.

There are a few ways around this.

1. The most obvious is to make sure that they are logged in to their machines as the domain user.
2. Grant rights to the SQL server to the user accounts that they are using. Not sure how to do this if their machine isn't a member of a domain.
3. **Recommended approach** Tthey can modify their SQL Server Management Studio shortcut (or create a new one) to use the `runas` command, which will run the specified executable using the credentials you provide (ie, they impersonate a different user for the purposes of that application and actions it performs). They'll need a user account in the server in order for this to work.

Example:

> C:\Windows\System32\runas.exe /netonly /user:MYDOMAIN\USERNAME ssms.exe

When you run this, you'll be prompted for the password for the user mydomain\username. I use this to connect to my SQL Server at work when VPN'ing from my home machine, and it works fine.

Another, slightly simpler option is to have them connect using SQL Server Authentication. You'll need to create a SQL Server account either for each user, or a generic account that they all can use, and, of course, give them the password.

Comment: What if they dont have a SSMS installed?

Comment: If they aren't trying to connect with SSMS, what ARE they using? If it's an application that they're running, you should just create a SQL Server account for that app and alter their connection strings to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Ivan, you are using the [`Windows Authentication Mode (Windows Authentication)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144284.aspx) , you have two options to deal with your issue.

1) Change to `SQL Server Authentication`, to do this in your connection string you must provide the credentials (login and password) every time that they connect and verify which your Sql Server is running  in [SQL Server Authentication Mode and Windows Authentication mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188670.aspx). check this [page](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2005) to see alternatives to your current connection string.

2) Keep the `Windows Authentication Mode`. you must add  the account of the user to the windows server where SQL server is running.

Comment: What steps do i have to take on alternative 2?