# sql server 2005 connecting thru windows authentication

Tags: java, sql-server

How would I be able to connect to MS SQL Server 2005 through Windows authentication from JAVA.
Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Can I connect to SQL Server using Windows Authentication from Java EE webapp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167464/can-i-connect-to-sql-server-using-windows-authentication-from-java-ee-webapp)

Has answers for both M$ & jTDS drivers