# MSSQL JDBC on unix

Tags: java, sql-server-2005, mssql-jdbc

I am trying to integrate a web tool we have with a sql server database using Integrated Security. I have been looking around trying to find a unix version of the sqljdbc4.jar however I cannot seem to find one with .so files only .dll's.

Does anyone know where I can get a version with the .so files required or another way to use integrated security?

Currently my application is failing to connect with

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: This driver is not configured for integrated authentication
```

and I can see

```
WARNING: Failed to load the sqljdbc_auth.dll
```

earlier in the logs.

Using version 2.5 of mssqljdbc.

Comment: Just a thought, if Integrated Security means security integration with  Windows OS,  you won't be able to do that on Unix out-of-the-box.  Why do you need integrated security?

Comment: The people that manage the database only allow this type of login. Was not aware it meant Windows OS integration thought it was just OS integration. They seemed to think it was possible on a unix server will have to check with them again.

Comment: The SO answer here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/167464/can-i-connect-to-sql-server-using-windows-authentication-from-java-ee-webapp) may give you more info

Comment: Hi Brain the question you linked seems to be about a Tomcat instance on Windows. The back end process is running on unix and I would like to log in with the user running that process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [these docs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg558122.aspx), beginning with MSSQL JDBC Driver 4.0, you should be able to specify `authenticationScheme=JavaKerberos` to use the pure Java Kerberos implementation that doesn't need sqljdbc_auth.dll.

Note, I haven't tried this.

Answer (score 0):

I know its late but for anyone searching this, try the following:

put the sqljdbc_auth.dll in your resource folder then add the following code

```
ClassLoader classLoader = TestDBConnection.class.getClassLoader();
File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("sqljdbc_auth.dll").getFile());
System.setProperty("java.library.path", file.getParent());
```