# Connect to SQL Server using Windows Authentication with different user account in JDBC

Tags: jdbc, sqljdbc, mssql-jdbc

I need to connect to SQL Server using Windows Authentication with different user account in JDBC. This is the code I am using:

```
static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:sqlserver://IP:port; databaseName=xyz; integratedSecurity=false; domain=abc";

Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);
```

And here is the Error:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'abcd'

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/167464/can-i-connect-to-sql-server-using-windows-authentication-from-java-ee-webapp

Comment: sorry for late reply. Thanks for the response!! I am using jdbc 1.2 and via sql server mangment studio I can log in to that sql server using different user account in 'Run as' and when i try with above code it doesn't connect. Do you think using jtds it may fix this or I need to install highest version of jdbc???

Answer (score 1):

Like described in question given by @konstantin-v-salikhov you need to set `integratedSecurity=true` if you actually want to use Integrated Authentication (and in that case it will autenticate as the user running the application). You also need the sqljdbc_auth.dll file to be [installed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428.aspx). When you make the actual call you shouldn't provide any username or password, just do something like this:

```
Properties info = new Properties();
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, info);
```

If you want to use SQL Server authentication (like you are doing in your code sample) you need to enable mixed mode authentication for your SQL Server instance.

Comment: thanks for the reply! but i want a particular user authentication to be used in windows authentication for every run. is it possible?