# Unable to connect to local SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, jdbc

I'm unable to connect to a local SQL Server with jdbc. This server is authenticated by  `Windows Authentication`. One thing to mention is that I successfully connected to a remote SQL Server with `SQL Server Authentication`.

[image]

My code:

```
String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;integratedSecurity=true;databaseName=TP3S;";
String driver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
```

I have enabled TCP/IP:

[image]

Any ideas? Thanks!

--UPDATE--

I have just started SQL Server Browser, now I'm getting the error:

```
WARNING: Failed to load the sqljdbc_auth.dll cause : no sqljdbc_auth in java.library.path
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: This driver is not configured for integrated authentication.
```

--UPDATE--

I solved the previous problem by adding `-Djava.library.path="DLL path"` in Run->Run configuration->Apache Tomcat->Arguments. But now I'm getting this error:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication.
```

Comment: [Similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/167464/can-i-connect-to-sql-server-using-windows-authentication-from-java-ee-webapp)

Comment: I have read this question but it's not working for me.

Comment: Is the SQL Server browser service running, otherwise JDBC can't connect to a named instance.

Answer (score 1):

Under TCP/IP you can enable by IP address. Check if IPs are enabled.

Comment: I have 15 IP Addresses under TCP/IP, and none of them are enabled! How do I know which one I should enable?