# Connect Java with MySQL using Windows Authentication?

Tags: java, mysql

Can anyone explain me how to connect Java with MySQL?

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
Connection conn = null;
...
try {
    conn =
       DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test?" +
                                   "user=monty&password=greatsqldb");

     } 
catch (SQLException ex) 
    {

       System.out.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
       System.out.println("SQLState: " + ex.getSQLState());
       System.out.println("VendorError: " + ex.getErrorCode());
    }
```

This is how i made it but mine is windows authentication and not password authentication.
So how to complete the connection with windows authentication?

Comment: mysql or sqlServer ??? in title it's mysql in tags it's sqlServer

Comment: Take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/167464/1741542

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java connectivity with MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839321/java-connectivity-with-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

You are not loading the driver class.

Try this -

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test?" + "user=monty&password=greatsqldb");
```

P.S. I have assumed you are using `MySQL`.

Answer (score 1):

First load the driver class

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test","monty","greatsqldb");
```

then create connections.

Comment: That's done. But this is for sqlserver authentication. and mine is windows authentication. How to connect with that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test","monty","greatsqldb");
```

You can specify the `username` and `password` seperately.

FYI : It is not necessary to load the driver using Class.forName() method but to be on safe side, coders use this method to load the drivers.

[Read](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html) This. It is written that `Applications no longer need to explictly load JDBC drivers using Class.forName().`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you use the MySQL External Authentication for Windows (http://www.mysql.com/products/enterprise/security.html).

This is supported in Connector/Net driver (.NET), using 'Integrated Security=yes' as connection string option: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connector-net-programming-authentication-windows-native.html

I can't find any documentation about support for this in the Connector/J reference (Java).
I guess it's not supported in the Java driver.