# Maven and ntlmauth.dll

Tags: java, maven, jdbc

In order to use native windows authentication with SQL Server, I'm told I need a DLL called "ntlmauth.dll" in my system path. I am using Maven to manage my dependencies. Can I manage this dependency with Maven, or do I need to manually install it anywhere I want to run this?

If it matters, I'm using jtds (because it's got a Maven package) and I'm getting the "Native SSPI library not loaded" message, which lead me to needing the DLL.

Comment: With the Microsoft SQL Server JDBC driver 4.0 you can also use Kerberos authentication which doesn't need the native dll, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg558122%28v=sql.110%29.aspx

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Does that work with jTDS?

Comment: I have no idea, afaik `ntlmauth.dll` is also Microsoft specific.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Added information to question in case I'm totally off base to begin with

Comment: Perhaps a relevant thread for your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/167464/can-i-connect-to-sql-server-using-windows-authentication-from-java-ee-webapp

Comment: My fault: `ntlmauth.dll` is from jTDS, Microsofts JDBC driver has `sqljdbc_auth.dll`. I don't know if jTDS has Kerberos support.