# How to formate JNDI to authenticate with a domain user instead of SQL user

Tags: java, sql-server, jndi, windowsdomainaccount

I have a working `JNDI` with SQL server username and password in my Java application. It throws `NameNotFoundException` when I try to change the user to my domain user instead of SQL user.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167464/can-i-connect-to-sql-server-using-windows-authentication-from-java-ee-webapp) it is mentioned I only have to provide `integratedSecurity` as true. Have I missed anything in my JNDI?

JNDI with SQL Server User:

```
<Resource
name="jdbc/MyJNDI"
auth="Container"
type="javax.sql.DataSource"
maxTotal="100"
maxIdle="30"
maxWaitMillis="1000"
validationQuery="select 1"
testOnBorrow="true"
testOnConnect="true"
testOnReturn="true"
testWhileIdle="true"
factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;database=survey;user=myuser;password=mypassword;"
/>
```

My JNDI with domain user:

```
<Resource
name="jdbc/MyJNDI"
auth="Container"
type="javax.sql.DataSource"
maxTotal="100"
maxIdle="30"
maxWaitMillis="1000"
validationQuery="select 1"
testOnBorrow="true"
testOnConnect="true"
testOnReturn="true"
testWhileIdle="true"
factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;database=survey;integratedSecurity=true;"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another driver is necessary. See this source http://www.bigdata-unleashed.com/20150930/database-ntlm-authentifizierung

```
<Resource
name="jdbc/MyJNDI"
auth="Container"
type="javax.sql.DataSource"
maxTotal="100"
maxIdle="30"
maxWaitMillis="1000"
integratedSecurity="true"
validationQuery="select 1"
testOnBorrow="true"
testOnConnect="true"
testOnReturn="true"
testWhileIdle="true"
factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
driverClassName="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"
url="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433;database=survey;"
/>
```

Database driver is available at http://sourceforge.net/projects/jtds/files/jtds/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried changing the driver and JNDI but it still gives me the same error. I uploaded the driver in lib folder, replaced my JNDI entry and restarted the service. Is there any other thing I have to check?